# 3D DirectX - How to get a proper rotation with a static camera?

Tags: matrix, rotation, directx

For a school project, we're modifying a game engine we built in an earlier course to support the Oculus Rift. However, one problem we've always had with it is that the world seems to rotate as we move the mouse. In a normal first-person scenario, one could move around with the camera without any trouble whatsoever, but in our engine randomly moving the mouse will eventually turn the world upside down. Moving the mouse in circles will straighten it out again.

My guess is that this happens because, since the camera is static, the position of the axes never changes and that this, in turn causes the unwanted rotation. Is there a way to compensate for this rotation, for example by determining an arbitrary axis and rotating around that? Or is the problem something else altogether and are we looking in the wrong area entirely?

We're not allowed to use DirectX methods outside the renderer, so we do all the matrix multiplications ourselves.

EDIT: Here is the code we use to rotate the camera. It's contained in two classes. First, the rotation code in Camera.cpp (our earlier assignment called for us to handle input in the camera):

```
void Camera::rotateByX(float angle)
{
    float rotX = -1.0f * angle / 1000.0f;
    xAngle = angle;
    //This is the calculation with the Rotion Matrix values of X
    matrixRotateX[5] = cos(rotX);
    matrixRotateX[6] = sin(rotX);
    matrixRotateX[9] = -sin(rotX);
    matrixRotateX[10] = cos(rotX);

    //The for loop to multiply the matrices
    float matrix[16];
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = matrixMultiply(changeMatrix, matrixRotateX)[i];
    }
    setChangeMatrix(matrix);
};

void Camera::rotateByY(float angle)
{   
    float rotY = -1.0f * angle / 1000.0f;
    //This is the calculation with the Rotion Matrix values of Y
    matrixRotateY[0] = cos(rotY);
    matrixRotateY[2] = -sin(rotY);
    matrixRotateY[8] = sin(rotY);
    matrixRotateY[10] = cos(rotY);

    //The for loop Multiply the matrices
    float matrix[16];
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        matrix[i] = matrixMultiply(changeMatrix, matrixRotateY)[i];
    }
    setChangeMatrix(matrix);
};
```

Matrix multiplication happens with this monstrosity:

```
float* Camera::matrixMultiply(float matrix1[16], float matrix2[16])
{
    if(matrix1 != NULL && matrix2 != NULL)
    {
    float matrix[16];
    float coord = (matrix1[0] * matrix2[0] + matrix1[1] * matrix2[4] + matrix1[2] * matrix2[8] + matrix1[3] * matrix2[12]);
    matrix[0] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[0] * matrix2[1] + matrix1[1] * matrix2[5] + matrix1[2] * matrix2[9] + matrix1[3] * matrix2[13]);
    matrix[1] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[0] * matrix2[2] + matrix1[1] * matrix2[6] + matrix1[2] * matrix2[10] + matrix1[3] * matrix2[14]);
    matrix[2] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[0] * matrix2[3] + matrix1[1] * matrix2[7] + matrix1[2] * matrix2[11] + matrix1[3] * matrix2[15]);
    matrix[3] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[4] * matrix2[0] + matrix1[5] * matrix2[4] + matrix1[6] * matrix2[8] + matrix1[7] * matrix2[12]);
    matrix[4] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[4] * matrix2[1] + matrix1[5] * matrix2[5] + matrix1[6] * matrix2[9] + matrix1[7] * matrix2[13]);
    matrix[5] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[4] * matrix2[2] + matrix1[5] * matrix2[6] + matrix1[6] * matrix2[10] + matrix1[7] * matrix2[14]);
    matrix[6] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[4] * matrix2[3] + matrix1[5] * matrix2[7] + matrix1[6] * matrix2[11] + matrix1[7] * matrix2[15]);
    matrix[7] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[8] * matrix2[0] + matrix1[9] * matrix2[4] + matrix1[10] * matrix2[8] + matrix1[11] * matrix2[12]);
    matrix[8] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[8] * matrix2[1] + matrix1[9] * matrix2[5] + matrix1[10] * matrix2[9] + matrix1[11] * matrix2[13]);
    matrix[9] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[8] * matrix2[2] + matrix1[9] * matrix2[6] + matrix1[10] * matrix2[10] + matrix1[11] * matrix2[14]);
    matrix[10] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[8] * matrix2[3] + matrix1[9] * matrix2[7] + matrix1[10] * matrix2[11] + matrix1[11] * matrix2[15]);
    matrix[11] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[12] * matrix2[0] + matrix1[13] * matrix2[4] + matrix1[14] * matrix2[8] + matrix1[15] * matrix2[12]);
    matrix[12] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[12] * matrix2[1] + matrix1[13] * matrix2[5] + matrix1[14] * matrix2[9] + matrix1[15] * matrix2[13]);
    matrix[13] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[12] * matrix2[2] + matrix1[13] * matrix2[6] + matrix1[14] * matrix2[10] + matrix1[15] * matrix2[14]);
    matrix[14] = coord;
    coord = (matrix1[12] * matrix2[3] + matrix1[13] * matrix2[7] + matrix1[14] * matrix2[11] + matrix1[15] * matrix2[15]);
    matrix[15] = coord;

    return matrix; 
    }
    else
    {
        Logger::getInstance()->logWarning("Matrix is invalid.", __LINE__, "Camera");
    }
};
```

Then, in the file Scene.cpp the results of these multiplications are called in the following method:

```
void Scene::updateMatrices()
{
    //Change the matrices of all the Entities
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i)
    {
        float matrix[16];
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
        {
                matrix[j] = entities[i]->matrixMultiply(camera->getChangeMatrix())[j];
        }
        entities[i]->setMatrix(matrix);
    }
    //Change the matrices of the Terrain
    float trMatrix[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
            trMatrix[i] = terrain->matrixMultiply(camera->getChangeMatrix())[i];
    }
    terrain->setMatrix(trMatrix);
    //Change the matrices of the Skybox
    float skyMatrix[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        skyMatrix[i] = skybox->matrixMultiply(camera->getChangeMatrix())[i];
    }
    //The skybox does not move. Therefore we set its translation values to zero. 
    //This is necessary because the change matrix does contain trnaslation values.
    skyMatrix[12] = 0.0f;
    skyMatrix[13] = 0.0f;
    skyMatrix[14] = 0.0f;
    skyMatrix[15] = 1.0f;
    skybox->setMatrix(skyMatrix);
    //Resets the Change Matrix of the Camera
    camera->resetMatrix();
};
```

As is clear from this code, we're rather like Top Gear UK: Ambitious but rubbish. I hope anything can be learned from this mess. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show how you rotate the camera. It's likely that this code contains some errors. Instead of correcting an error, you should try not to make it in the first place.

Comment: Oculus Rift in a school project? Not bad! Anyway we need to see relevant code. Programmers not supposed to guess, but my guesses is a camera logic, math functions, or CPU-GPU data exchange (such as constant buffers update). As general advices: use debugger extensively: watch variables, make conditional breakpoints, and test, until you find where rotation goes wrong. You can try to temporary swap implementation of your own math to some kind of known-working one, such as DirectX math. Also Check DirectX math source code for inspiration (it's an header-only lib, all functions are inlined).

Comment: At first sight, this smells like [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).